# Вывод значения переменной из JS в div

Tags: javascript, html

Есть js код:

```
for(var i=1; i<10; i++){
document.getElementById('txt1') = i;
}
```

Он должен выводить значение переменной i в:

```
<div id='txt1'></div>
```

но не выводит =(

Перерыл Интернет в поисках ответа, как правильно вывести значение переменной в блок с id, но ничего конкретного не нашел, хотя вопрос довольно простой. Как можно правильно сделать?

Comment: .

    document.getElementById('txt1').innerHTML = i;

Comment: Пробовал, выдает Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: Так он у вас не будет работать, потому что у вас в цикле все значения присваиваются в один и тот же ID, хоть бы какое-нибудь условие придумали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В момент выполнения кода ваш элемент еще не загрузился, поэтому необходимо обернуть все в `window.onload`, чтобы код выполнялся только после полной загрузки страницы:

```
window.onload = function() {
    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        document.getElementById('txt1').innerHTML = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Лучше так: 

>> document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {}, false );

Comment: Отлично работает, спасибо, но выводит только последнее число, как можно вывести все?

Comment: @redsensor, 

>>document.getElementById('txt1').innerHTML += i;

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает.